# Jest mock testing with protobuf

Tags: jestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protobuf.js

I am curious if there are testing examples using jest, using dynamically generated node clients in build/protobuf

I am implementing a node client which dynamically generate protobuf files of the service it is calling, and calls the service via grpc. I am confused as how do we mock .proto files